# Apache Cordova load external website with exclusive app feature

Tags: javascript, android, apache, cordova, jsp

I have a requirement where I need to migrate a website into an Apache Cordova app with minimal effort. I also need to add an extra feature that is not doable without native permissions.

The existing website contains enormous JSP content. As given [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2481899), I cannot use JSP files with Cordova. So, I'm thinking of loading (redirecting to) that website into the app. For the extra feature, I would need a two way communication between the website & the app.

I have done that previously between a native app and locally embedded HTML pages. But since the website is not locally hosted, Is the communication still possible ?

Comment: You can show the website in the app, there's no problem in that part, but what do you mean by the 2-way communication for example?

Comment: By two way communication, I mean I should be able to send data to the website from the native app and should be able to receive data as well.